Is it possible set event callback on inside a component and outside a component and have callbacks both run?
I want to run two functions: one on:blur inside a component, and one on the component from the outside.
// CustomInput.svelte

<input on:blur={() => console.log(1)} />

// App.svelte
import CustomInput from "./CustomInput.svelte";

<CustomInput on:blur={() => console.log(2)} />

When the blur event is triggered 1 is logged in the console. Is there a way to run both callbacks and get 1 and 2 logged in the console?

You can forward the event in addition to handling it:
<input on:blur={() => console.log(1)} on:blur />


The best solution I can think of:
// CustomInput.svelte

<script>
  import { createEventDispatcher } from "svelte";

  function handleBlur(event) {
    console.log(1);
    dispatch("blur", { event });
  }
</script>

<input on:blur={handleBlur} />

// App.svelte
import CustomInput from "./CustomInput.svelte";

<CustomInput on:blur={() => console.log(2)} />

It would also be possible to send a function as a prop, then run it in handleBlur. The reason I choose to dispatch blur is because I think it increases code readability.
